# How do I get s3cmd to install on CentOS 7.2?

Tags: centos

Following the instructions from the link below doesn't work as expected since they are for CentOS 6.6 and I'm running 7.2. In the past I've installed s3cmd via yum and it works just fine. Now, however, yum is telling me that s3cmd depends on python 2.6 whereas my server is running 2.7. Is my best approach to install python 2.6 alongside 2.7, or to compile s3cmd from source and go that route? I'm a bit out of my element either way so I'm grateful for any input here.

(This is what I already tried, to no avail)

https://s3bubble.com/installing-s3cmd-on-centos-6-6/

Comment: Please show the actual command(s) that you used and their output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the page you linked](https://s3bubble.com/installing-s3cmd-on-centos-6-6/), it points to http://s3tools.org/repositories.  According to the official [Amazon S3 Tools site](http://s3tools.org/download):

> S3cmd requires Python 2.6 (or newer)

and

> Note: the [LINUX repositories at http://s3tools.org/repositories] are
>   NOT up to date. Download the latest version of S3cmd from SourceForge
>   or GitHub above or get the s3cmd package from your Linux
>   distribution's own repositories.

If `yum install s3cmd` with your default repos (or possibly EPEL) does not work for some reason, then you can install from SourceForge.  The latest release is 1.6.1, so download that from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/s3tools/files/s3cmd/1.6.1/s3cmd-1.6.1.tar.gz/download).  Once you have it downloaded, do the following:

```
$ tar -xzf s3cmd-1.6.1.tar.gz
$ cd s3cmd-1.6.1
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

This will extract the .tar.gz file, and navigate into the extracted folder, and run the s3cmd install script.

Note, that according to the [INSTALL file](https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/blob/v1.6.1/INSTALL), you need the Python "distutils" module:

> You will however need Python "distutils" module for this to  work. It
>   is often part of the core python package (e.g. in  OpenSuse Python 2.5
>   package) or it can be installed using your package manager, e.g. in
>   Debian use
>
> `apt-get install python-setuptools`
>
> Again, consult your distribution documentation on how to 
>   find out the actual package name and how to install it then.

Comment: Sorry for the delay responding. Finally have a chance to return to server duties. Anyway, I tried installing per your instructions and am now receiving this: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 7, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup
ImportError: No module named setuptools` And when I run `python --version` I see this: `Python 2.7.5`

Comment: I'm running `python setup.py install` as root from the extracted s3cmd-1.6.1 directory, FYI.

Comment: According to the [INSTALL file](https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/blob/v1.6.1/INSTALL):
You will however need Python "distutils" module for this to work. It is often part of the core python package (e.g. in OpenSuse Python 2.5 package) or it can be installed using your package manager, e.g. in Debian use `apt-get install python-setuptools`

I'll update my answer to include this info.

Comment: Excellent @Ryan! Thanks for your help, Ryan. I ran `yum install python-setuptools` and then `python setup.py install` and am up and running (I don't have apt-get installed). I'm marking your answer as accepted. Much obliged.